# Obliviousness & Oblivion - True synonyms? (e.g., "Blame it on his obliviousness" vs. "Blame it on his oblivion")

Tags: synonyms

I saw a comment online where someone said something akin to "He got in that accident due to his oblivion to the situation." I'd never heard "oblivion" used to describe someone as being oblivious ***to*** something. Rather, I've almost always heard it used to describe a figurative place of forgotten things--usually a place you figuratively ***enter into*** or ***exit from***. E.g., "The villain was cast ***into*** oblivion, never to be heard from or spoken of again."

For more examples, here are the [example sentences of "oblivion"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivion) offered by the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

> The technology is ***destined*** for oblivion.
>
> The names of the people who lived here long ago have faded ***into***
> oblivion.
>
> His theories have faded ***into*** scientific oblivion.
>
> Her work was rescued ***from*** oblivion when it was rediscovered in the
> early 1900s.
>
> After being awake for three days straight, he longed for the oblivion
> of sleep.
>
> She drank herself ***into*** oblivion.
>
> The little village was bulldozed ***into*** oblivion to make way for the
> airport.

And here are [example sentences of "obvliousness"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obliviousness) from the Cambridge English dictionary:

> Their seeming obliviousness ***to*** her presence upset her.
>
> He has an obliviousness ***to*** others' needs.
>
> She was frustrated by his obliviousness ***to*** existing research.

If I were to rewrite the first sentence I mentioned, I would change it to "He got in that accident due to his obliviousness to the situation." As standalone words, the word "obvliousness" sounds more cumbersome and clunky to me than the word "oblivion", but it sounds more correct to me when describing someone as oblivious or ignorant to their surroundings.

However, [Thesaurus.com indeed lists "oblivion" as a synonym for "obliviousness"](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/obliviousness). So even though "He got in that accident due to his *oblivion* to the situation" may not be incorrect (but let me know if it is), am I correct in thinking it would be more common to phrase it as "He got in that accident due to his *obliviousness* to the situation," perhaps even to the point that many would think the former to be incorrect?

Comment: Hello, velkoon. Since there are vanishingly few true synonyms, the definition 'one of two or more words interchangeable in some contexts with no or negligible change in meaning / connotation' is used, not the useless 'one of two or more words interchangeable in all contexts with no or negligible change in meaning / connotation'. Hence, one needs not to make undue claims when looking at lists of synonyms. // Here, although [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblivion) does add the 'obliviousness' sense for 'oblivion', I'd always distinguish the words' (default) meanings.

Comment: If you want to know what a word means, look at the definitions, and specifically-chosen example sentences from multiple dictionaries. Using a thesaurus or "example sentences selected automatically from various online news sources" is less reliable. If you look for example in Merriam-Webster it is clear that the two are not identical.

Comment: To be fair, 'He drank himself into oblivion' sounds the better choice to my ears; 'obliviousness' has more connection with the situation that needs addressing:  'In spite of his compromised immune system and the number of neighbours who were confined due to Covid, he displayed a worrying obliviousness.'

Comment: Short hint at an answer: 1) there are no true synonyms 2) even if you allow for that, these two are pretty different 3) obliviousness is about one person being unaware of something and oblivion is nobody being aware of -that- person.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reason I have already mentioned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Blame it on his oblivion" does not compare to *his obliviousness*. Was he unknown or dense? They're not similar.